# Skip Records by String Matching

Tags: c#, string, .net-core

I'm looping through a large excel file full of Products. We want to only process rows where Brand = x, or Product = 'y'. The following code worked there was a predictable filter ie. Product1, however we are unsure what data the xsl file will hold and it could be something like "Product1 (buy me)" which wouldn't pass with this logic and the record would get ignored.

What technique can we use to match Product names with our filters? Regex, pattern matching etc. ? Or do I simply need to split the filter and loop through each? Seems like there shuold be a more elegant way.

```
    private static bool SkipRecord(string strFilters, string key, DataRow row)
    {
     //include the record if it matches our filter
     var strField = row[key].ToString();
     bool skip = true;
     if (strField != null && strField != "")
     {
         skip = !strFilters.ToLower().Contains(strField.ToLower());
     }
     return skip;
 }

 List<ResultRow> xlsRows = new List<ResultRow>();
 foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
 {
    if (SkipRecord(f.brandFlag, "Brand", row) && SkipRecord(f.productFlag, "Name", row))
        continue;
 }
```

appSettings.json

```
"CustomSettings": {
"BrandFlag": "Gibson|Fender|Jackson",
"ProductFlag": "Product 1|ProductTwo|Product3",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(One comment first, I think the first method is missing the

```
return skip;
```

line).

For the specific case you mentioned it would work if you changed the order of the "Contains" arguments:

```
skip = !strField.ToLower().Contains(strFilters.ToLower());
```

Comment: Added the return statement. Changing the order of arguments does not solve the issue since we don't know what strField will hold